# re.sub() - Regex for replacing last occurance of a substring in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to replace the last occurrence of a substring from a string using re.sub in Python but stuck with the regex pattern. Can someone help me to get the correct pattern?

```
String = "cr US TRUMP DE NIRO 20161008cr_x080b.wmv"
```

or

`String  = "crcrUS TRUMP DE NIRO 20161008cr.xml"`

I want to replace the last occurrence of "`cr`" and anything before the extension.

desired output strings are -

```
"cr US TRUMP DE NIRO 20161008.wmv"
"crcrUS TRUMP DE NIRO 20161008.xml"
```

I'm using `re.sub` to replace it.

```
re.sub('pattern', '', String)
```

Please advise.

Comment: `pattern` is your pattern? well of course that's not going to work...

Comment: Please show the actual pattern and string you are using.

Comment: [`cr(?!.*cr)[^.]*`](https://regex101.com/r/CL0VOT/1)

Comment: My pattern didn't work because I don't know much about regular expressions and that's why I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using a greedy quantifier and a capture group:

```
re.sub(r'(.*)cr[^.]*', '\\1', input)
```

Comment: This is neat but will not work if input is `acr.crt`

Comment: @anubhava: There are several cases this pattern doesn't work, you can also consider a filename with several dots. It's obviously not a waterproof pattern, it's more a simple illustration of how to reach the last occurrence using the greediness. Once you get the idea, you can improve it for a particular use case.

Answer (score 7):

The alternative solution using `str.rfind(sub[, start[, end]])` function:

```
string = "cr US TRUMP DE NIRO 20161008cr_x080b.wmv"
last_position = string.rfind('cr')
string = string[:last_position] + string[string.rfind('.'):]

print(string)  #cr US TRUMP DE NIRO 20161008.wmv
```

Besides, `rfind` will go much faster in such case:
here is measurement results:
using `str.rfind(...)` : **0.0054836273193359375**
using `re.sub(...)`       : **0.4017353057861328**

Comment: Best option imo. No point in putting in regexps when they are not needed. It's already debatable whether it's good putting them in when they are needed…

Comment: @spectras, yes, of course. Besides, it works much faster in such cases

Answer (score 2):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
repl = re.sub(r"cr((?!cr)[^.])*(?=\.[^.]+$)", "", input);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hCL1WB/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
cr         # match cr
(?:        # non-capturing group start
   (?!     # negative lookahead start
      cr   # match cr
   )       # negative lookahead end
   [^.]    # match anything but DOT
)          # non-capturing group end
*          # match 0 or more of matching character that doesn't have cr at next postion
(?=        # positive lookahead start
   \.      # match DOT
   [^.]+   # followed by 1 or more anything but DOT
   $       # end of input
)          # postive lookahead end
```

Comment: happened upon this, well laid out response.