# Remove only the last occurance of the words from string

Tags: python, string

I have a string and an array of phrases.

```
input_string = 'alice is a character from a fairy tale that lived in a wonder land. A character about whome no one knows much about'

phrases_to_remove = ['wonderland', 'character', 'no one']
```

Now what I want to do is, remove the last occurrences of the words in the array `phrases_to_remove` from the `input_string`.

```
output_string = 'alice is a character from a fairy tale that lived in a. A about whome knows much about'
```

I've written down a method that takes in the input string and either an `array` or just a `string` to replace and have used the `rsplit()` to replace the phrases.

```
def remove_words_from_end(actual_string: str, to_replace, occurrence: int):
    if isinstance(to_replace, list):
        output_string = actual_string
        for string in to_replace:
            output_string = ' '.join(output_string.rsplit(string, maxsplit=occurrence))
        return output_string.strip()
    elif isinstance(to_replace, str):
        return ' '.join(actual_string.rsplit(to_replace, maxsplit=occurrence)).strip()
    else:
        raise TypeError('the value "to_replace" must be a string or a list of strings')
```

The issue with the code is, I can't remove the words that have a `space` mismatch. For example `wonder land` and `wonderland`.

Is there a way I can do it without compromising much on performance?

Comment: If you want the code to remove `wonder land` when asked to remove `wonderland`, do you want the code to remove `now here` when asked to remove `nowhere`? How are you supposed to distinguish "space mismatches" from legitimate spaces?

Comment: @JohnColeman yeah basically the white space shouldn't be a factor that causes the strings not to get removed. Yeah that's exactly it. How can one remove words from an input array ignoring white spaces

Comment: And re can't be used ```re.sub(phrases_to_remove[0], '' , input_string)```

Comment: @jackotonye how would `re` handle the `white space`?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239249/re-sub-regex-for-replacing-last-occurance-of-a-substring-in-a-string for last occurrences

Comment: @jackotonye I already have the last occurrences figured out. See my code above.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to replace non matches in the string but you can use `Hyphenator ` to split the word to be matched `from hyphen import Hyphenator` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyHyphen/

Comment: @jackotonye That is a good suggestion if OP is only worried about spaces which make some semantic sense. The problem description suggests that they would also want to remove things like `wo nderland`, but perhaps they don't really worry about such random typos.

Comment: @JohnColeman that's quite accurate. The issue is the input string might have random white space typos as the program is supposed to be for the people who don't really know how to read or write and that's why I am facing a tough time with the white spaces as they tend to occur quite randomly

Comment: Then in that case it seems like you have a hard problem, one for which  regular expressions don't seem too helpful. I don't see any shortcut to computing a lot of Levenshtein distances, especially since it seems arbitrary to focus on a stray space as the only possible typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `re` to handle the possible whitespace is a possibility:

```
import re

def remove_last(word, string):
    pattern = ' ?'.join(list(word))
    matches = list(re.finditer(pattern, string))
    if not matches:
        return string
    last_m = matches[-1]
    sub_string = string[:last_m.start()]
    if last_m.end() < len(string):
        sub_string += string[last_m.end():]
    return sub_string

def remove_words_from_end(words, string):
    words_whole = [word.replace(' ', '') for word in words]
    string_out = string
    for word in words:
        string_out = remove_last(word, string_out)
    return string_out
```

And running some tests:

```
>>> input_string = 'alice is a character from a fairy tale that lived in a wonder land. A character about whome no one knows much about'
>>> phrases_to_remove = ['wonderland', 'character', 'no one']
>>> remove_words_from_end(phrases_to_remove, input_string)
'alice is a character from a fairy tale that lived in a . A  about whome  knows much about'
>>> phrases_to_remove = ['wonder land', 'character', 'noone']
>>> remove_words_from_end(phrases_to_remove, input_string)
'alice is a character from a fairy tale that lived in a . A  about whome  knows much about'
```

In this example the regex search pattern is just the word with a possible space `' ?'` in-between each character.

Comment: great works lovely but throws an `IndexError: list index out of range` when I reverse the case scenario e.g. `['wonder land', 'character', 'no one']` and the `input_string` contains `wonderland`. Can this solution handle this case as well?

Comment: Hmmm...can the list of match words be processed to remove any spaces? The end result should be the same, right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: @ZoltanDeWitt you may want to process to_replace<list> by removing spaces.

Comment: @iam.Carrot Process the word list `['wonder land', 'character', 'no one']` to be `['wonderland', 'character', 'noone']` since they will all match on any spaces between letters anyways

Comment: @ZoltanDeWitt Yeah that can be done. I should have thought about that. +1 Can you please update your answer so that I can mark it as an answer

Comment: @ZoltanDeWitt +1

Comment: @ZoltanDeWitt I have updated your answer but still in review process.

Comment: I edited to fix both the IndexError and add the pre-processing on the input words. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In general when comparing two strings s1 and s2 you could be checking if they are equal (same size and each character is the same - what the standard method used does) OR (the part you need to implement) if they differ by 1 on size and the character they differ on if a space. A sample function that does this is written below. In terms of performance this is an O(n) check where n is the length of the string but regardless the initial check was O(n) as well.

```
def almost_match(s1, s2):
  # If they have a single space of difference
  if len(s1) != len(s2) + 1 and len(s2) != len(s1) + 1:
    return False
  i = 0 # counter for s1 characters
  j = 0 # counter for s2 characters

  while i < len(s1) and j < len(s2):
    if s1[i] != s2[j]:
      if s1 == ' ':
        i = i + 1
        continue
      elif s2 == ' ':
        j = j + 1
        continue
      else:
        return False
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1

  if j < len(s2) and s2[j] == ' ':
    j = j + 1

  if i < len(s1) and s2[i] == ' ':
    i = i + 1

  return i == len(s1) and j == len(s2) # require that both strings matched fully
```

For the last line, note that it prevents the possibility of matching "abc" with "abcd"
This can be optimized, but this is the general idea

Comment: nah. It's not it. Won't work if there are two spaces between the words e.g. `wond er land` for `wonderland` I can't hard code the number of white spaces

Comment: If you remove the check for the 1 space then it would work. I just added it because I thought you meant 1 space. The code just ignores spaces if that's what's different