# Remove words with spaces or "-" in them Python

Tags: python, string

This is an extension to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48992197/3766231)

Now as in the linked question, the answer used a `space?` as a regex pattern to match a string with a space or no space in it.

**The Problem Statement:**

I have a string and an array of phrases.

```
input_string = 'alice is a character from a fairy tale that lived in a wonder land. A character about whome no-one knows much about'

phrases_to_remove = ['wonderland', 'character', 'noone']
```

Now what I want to do is to remove the last occurrences of the words in the array `phrases_to_remove` from the `input_string`.

```
output_string = 'alice is a character from a fairy tale that lived in a. A about whome knows much about'
```

**Notice:** the words to remove may or may not occur in the string and if they do, they may occur in either the same form {'wonderland' or 'character', 'noone'} or they may occur with a space or a hyphen (-) in between the words e.g. wonder land, no-one, character.

The issue with the code is, I can't remove the words that have a `space` or a `-` mismatch. For example `wonder land` and `wonderland` and `wonder-land`.

I tried the `(-)?|( )?` as a regex but couldn't get it to work.

I need help

Comment: have you tried `r'\bwonder[ \-]?land\b'` in your replacement list?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is that a regex?

Comment: it's a regex all right. `re.sub(r'\bwonder[ \-]?land\b',"",input_string)` removes the word all-right (preserving word boundaries as a bonus)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the word wonderland is not hard coded. The requirement is to remove all words that are a match irrespective of `-` or `space` between the letters

Comment: in that case, you have insert spaces/dashes between each letter, since you don't know when words "break"

Comment: I think you could shorten your question, as the block of code at the start doesn't help to understand the issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre done

Comment: this is much better. With the help of some commenters, I was able to create an answer.

Comment: The problem with your regex is probably precende... `"(-)?|( )?".join(["a", "b", "c"])` yields the regex `"a(-)?|( )?b(-)?|( )?c"` Note that it matches `a` or `a-`, `b` or `<space>b` or `<space>b-` or `b-` and `c` or `<space>c`. It does not match `a-b` or even `ab`. For that you want `a([- ])?b([- ]?)c` so you should try using `"([- ])?".join`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't see your answer

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta it doesn't work. I have a word like `wonder - land` notice the spaces between the word and the `-`

Comment: @iam.Carrot Then just use `*`: `"([- ]*)".join`. Or maybe you want something more precise like `"(\s*(-)?\s*)".join` which does not match things like `----`. the point is the grouping. By using `(-)?|( )` the alternation `|` is *not* just between `(-)?` and `( )` but its scope extends to the words around making it match stuff like `a-` or `b` but not `a-b`... Hope you got this

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta works like a charm please consider replying as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @iam.Carrot my answer is below. I have adapted it from your comments, as your original question didn't state that there could be _several_ space/dashes separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is grouping. Using `(-)?|( )?` as a separator does not do what you think it does.

Consider what happens when the list of words is `a,b`:

```
>>> regex = "(-)?|( )?".join(["a", "b"])
>>> regex
'a(-)?|( )?b'
```

You'd like this regex to match `ab` or `a b` or `a-b`, but clearly it does not do that. It matches `a`, `a-`, `b` or `<space>b` instead!

```
>>> re.match(regex, 'a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68c9f3b690>
>>> re.match(regex, 'a-')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68c9f3b718>
>>> re.match(regex, 'b')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68c9f3b690>
>>> re.match(regex, ' b')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68c9f3b718>
```

To fix this you can enclose the separator in its own group: `([- ])?`.

If you also want to match words like `wonder - land` (i.e. where there are spaces before/after the hyphen) you should use the following `(\s*-?\s*)?`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know where the separations can be, you could generate a regex made of ORed regexes (using word boundaries to avoid matching sub-words).

Those regexes would alternate the letters of the word and `[\s\-]*` (matching zero to several occurrences of "space" or "dash") using `str.join` on each character

```
import re

input_string = 'alice is a character from a fairy tale that lived in a wonder - land. A character about whome no one knows much about'

phrases_to_remove = ['wonderland', 'character', 'noone']

the_regex = "|".join(r"\b{}\b".format('[\s\-]*'.join(x)) for x in phrases_to_remove)
```

Now to handle the "replace everything but the first occurrence" part: let's define an object which will replace everything but the first match (using an internal counter)

```
class Replacer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__counter = 0

    def replace(self,m):
        if self.__counter:
            return ""
        else:
            self.__counter += 1
            return m.group(0)
```

now pass the `replace` method to `re.sub`:

```
print(re.sub(the_regex,Replacer().replace,input_string))
```

result:

```
alice is a character from a fairy tale that lived in a . A  about whome  knows much about
```

(the generated regex is pretty complex BTW: `\bw[\s\-]*o[\s\-]*n[\s\-]*d[\s\-]*e[\s\-]*r[\s\-]*l[\s\-]*a[\s\-]*n[\s\-]*d\b|\bc[\s\-]*h[\s\-]*a[\s\-]*r[\s\-]*a[\s\-]*c[\s\-]*t[\s\-]*e[\s\-]*r\b|\bn[\s\-]*o[\s\-]*o[\s\-]*n[\s\-]*e\b`)

Comment: The OP wants to remove only the *last* occurrence of the regex. So your output does not satisfy Op needs. I believe `re.sub` alone cannot work. you need to `re.finditer` and manually replace only the last occurrence... Alternatively: write the regex "backwards", revert the text and use `re.sub` with a `count=1`.

Comment: edited with a replacement function using a counter for side-effect. Now works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one at a time:

For space:

For '-' :

```
^[ \t]+
@"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+
```