# Looking to Regex Strip a predictable chunk of text from data frame

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp

I have a dataframe of Inspection results & Violations that looks like:

```
Results                 Violations
Pass w/ Conditions  3. MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE AND CONDITIONAL E

Pass                    36. THERMOMETERS PROVIDED & ACCURATE Comment...
```

What I need to do is have python loop through this pandas dataframe specifically in the violations column and identify all scenarios of
'Starts with a number and ends with Comments:'

I was able to use regex to strip the number with this line of code

```
df_new['Violations'] = df_new['Violations'].map(lambda x: 
    x.lstrip('0123456789.- ').rstrip('[^a-zA-Z]Comments[^a-zA-Z]'))
```

As you can see I tried to implement the comments closing end via the rstrip regex command but that does not appear to do anything. Output then looks like this

```
Results Violations
0   Pass w/ Conditions  MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE AND CONDITIONAL EMPL...
1   Pass    THERMOMETERS PROVIDED & ACCURATE - Comments: 4...
```

What is the regex command to basically say: Look for a number and delete everything between the number and Comments:

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

*What is the regex command to basically say: Look for a number and delete everything between the number and Comments:*

```
foo = '''\
Results                 Violations
Pass w/ Conditions  3. MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE AND CONDITIONAL E
Pass                    36. THERMOMETERS PROVIDED & ACCURATE Comment...'''
```

```
>>> print(foo)
    Results                 Violations
    Pass w/ Conditions  3. MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE AND CONDITIONAL E
    Pass                    36. THERMOMETERS PROVIDED & ACCURATE Comment...
>>>
```

```
import re
bar = re.sub('(\d+\.).*(Comment.*)', '\\1', foo)
```

```
>>> print(bar)
    Results                 Violations
    Pass w/ Conditions  3. MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE AND CONDITIONAL E
    Pass                    36.
>>>
```

**References:**

- https://regex101.com/
- [re.sub() - Regex for replacing last occurance of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239249/re-sub-regex-for-replacing-)

last-occurance-of-a-substring-in-a-string